# What is the trick for making jboss-client.jar available to the WAR applications in JBoss EAP 6

Tags: configuration, jboss, shared-libraries, jboss-eap-6

In JBoss EAP 6.1, there is a file

```
JBOSS/bin/client/jboss-client.jar
```

It contains all the client classes needed by web applications.  However, when we install a WAR file, it is not seeing these classes available to it.

To work around this, we have been including a copy of this JAR in the war files `WEB-INF/lib` folder.   These copies are a waste, but more importantly it means we have to have a different WAR file for every app server we want to install into.

Is there a trick to allow the applications in the WAR files to load and use the classes from this library where it is, without having to copy it into the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of the application?  Alternately, is there a place we can copy this jar so that it would be available to all WAR applications?

Comment: What's the purpose to use this library inside your war file?

Comment: What classes are you using from it? You likely just need to add a module dependency to your deployment. It just depends on what classes you're using so you know which module dependenc(y|ies) to add.

Comment: This JAR file contains classes that are needed by applications to talk to the JBoss server.  Potentially every class would be needed.  The real question is: why can't my applications see the classes in this JAR? The only purpose of the jar is for applications to talk to JBoss.  I am mystified about what I am doing wrong in every single application so that I can't access these classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to place a file named `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` in the WEB-INF folder.   The contents of that file was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <!-- Excluding conflicting JBoss-6 Implicit Modules so that jars bundled within war file is used. -->
    <exclusions>
        <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
    </exclusions>
    <!-- Defining additional dependencies for JMS usage in model API -->
    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.jboss.remote-naming" />
        <module name="org.hornetq" />
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

This allowed us to use the JMS classes from JBoss without having a copy of the client library included with the application being installed.  It seems that some time ago, a programmer ported the application to JBoss, and ran into a problem which was "solved" (hacked) by putting the client library in, but this is a far better solution.

Comment: Thanks you very much for this.

Answer (score 0):

Check Jboss Modules to make the lib available as an external module of Jboss.
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/chap-Class_Loading_and_Modules.html

Comment: This makes perfect sense if I was EXTENDING the server to have an additional module to provide functionality.  I don't understand why I need to do this for the jboss-client.jar which contains the classes for accessing JBoss functionality itself.  It just seems really ODD to have to create a module just to access the JBoss server you are running in?  What am I missing here?

Comment: @AgilePro Did you figure out why JBOSS makes you include such critical functionality (*jboss-client.jar*) explicitly via modules, instead of providing them as default?

Comment: @Daud see new answer which describes our solution